# find and replace special characters in PHP

Tags: php

Please tell me how to do a find and replace in **PHP**.

I nee to find **Entry="OK"** and replace with **OK** in a xml file.

I tried ***str_replace*** but confused because of the **=** and **"** in it.

Comment: In an xml file, you say? why not using and XML parser?

Comment: @Damien Pirsy. Can you kindly explain me more please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though I'm not sure of the environment you're working in, here's a php sample that I think does what you want:

```
<html>
<?php
$teststr = "Entry=\"OK\"";
print $teststr . "<br>";
$newanswer = str_replace($teststr, "Entry=OK", $teststr);
print $newanswer . "<br>";
?>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks. But I can not modify the source to show as **Entry=\"OK\"**. it is **Entry="OK"**. Please help

Comment: Just assign your input string to $teststr. The only reason I've used "Entry=\"OK\"" is because I don't have access to your input string variable.

Comment: Simply, in the XML file, it contains **Entry="OK"**. And I need to replace it with **OK**. The issue is, 'str_replace' doesn't work when '=' and '"' is there.

Comment: @Nuan J  On the contrary I think I've shown that str_replace works fine with those characters present. Can you show us what code you've tried?

Comment: You waked me up. Thanks Sir.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
str_replace('Entry="OK"','OK',$var);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use str_replace its working

```
 $r = 'Entry="OK" tyyuu hhh';
 echo str_replace($r,'Entry="OK"','OK');
```

if any error found then u use preg_replace with corresponding patteren

Comment: You got the wrong order of arguments, as for the rest it's no different than the other answers. Oh, btw, I'm not the downvoter of any answer here :)

Comment: Hi Damien why u dont give any answer or any idea